# TypeError in angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to mark some values in a list as font red color and rest default based on some condition.When I am trying to assign a boolean var for the particular data in the list I ma getting "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'match' of 123;
My code s :

```js
angular.forEach($scope.searchResults, function (value, index) {

  //populate searchResults
   $scope.searchResults[index].name = "ABC";
  
    $scope.searchResults[index].linkedRecords = [];
  if(//check some condition){
    $scope.searchResults[index].linkedRecords[i] ="123"; 
    $scope.searchResults[index].linkedRecords[i].match=true;
  }
    
  
  });
```

```html
 <tr data-ng-repeat="searchResult in searchResults ">
   
   <td >
            <span data-ng-repeat="source in searchResult.linkedRecords" >
                <span ng-if="!source.match">{{ source }}</span>
                <span ng-if="source.match" style="color: red">{{ source }}</span>
                <br>
            </span></td>
   </tr>
```

Any idea how can I make this work in html? I need to set something for each item and make those items in the list appear as red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the property to have a value of `123` then you are trying to access a property called `'match'`.

```
$scope.searchResults[index].linkedRecords[i] = 123;
```

At this point the value of `$scope.searchResults[index].linkedRecords[i]` is `123`.

Which means this line:

```
$scope.searchResults[index].linkedRecords[i].match=true;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(123).match = true;
```

This won't work, because the Number type is immutable, which means you can't add or modify properties on their immediate object representation.

---

You may want to *wrap* or *box* your number inside an object. Then you can add other properties to that object.

```
$scope.searchResults[index].linkedRecords[i] = { value: 123, match: true };
```

Then your HTML would look something like this instead.

```
<span data-ng-repeat="source in searchResult.linkedRecords" >
  <span ng-if="!source.match">{{ source.value }}</span>
  <span ng-if="source.match" style="color: red">{{ source.value }}</span>
  <br>
</span>
```

Comment: any idea how can i make this work in html? I need to set something and make those items in the list appear as red.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code? Maybe a sample data set for $scope.searchResults?

Comment: Wrap the numbers in an object.

`$scope.searchResults[index].linkedRecords[i] = { value: 123, match: true };`

Then do `source.match` and `source.value` in your HTML.

Comment: @Dan Prince : Thanks a lot...:)